# Java Image over image has white b/g even though it's a png

Tags: java, image, overlay

As seen below, I have a BufferedImage over another BufferedImage.  They are both pngs and I would like there to be no background on the overlayed image.  I'm sure there's so way to do this, but am unsure of where in the api.

Here's the method in question:

```
private static BufferedImage finalizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, String tokenImage, Integer occurrences, int height, int width, int type){

    //Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int strWidth = (fm.stringWidth(tokenImage));
    int imageWidth = resizedImage.getWidth();
    int textBegin = (imageWidth - strWidth) / 2;
    //g.setFont(font);
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    int textHeight = (fm.getAscent() + (TOKEN_HEIGHT - (fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent())) / 2);
    g.drawString(tokenImage, textBegin, textHeight); 

    //for multiple occurrences
    try {
        BufferedImage numOnSubscript = ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/ui/tokens/subscript.fw.png"));
        g.drawImage(numOnSubscript, width - 20, height-20, 20, 20, null);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(occurrences.toString(), width - 16, (height-20)*2 - 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;

}
```

Here is what is happening.

[image: overlay error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.  Of course, it's the silliest thing.  I had a white background on as default in fireworks :-/